# Android window background image disappears 5-10 seconds after the app is started. The result is black screen

Tags: android, image

I would ask about the following problem:

I have a window background image "`android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_splash`

When I run the App the background image is shown correctly but after 5-10 seconds it disappears and a black screen is shown.

The problem is reproduced on `Android 4.4.3`, but not reproduced on `Android 4.0.4`.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever have a solution for this? I am having similar problems.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Comment: I found a solution for it; reply if you want to know what I did.

Comment: I would like to know, thanks.

Comment: What are your dimensions of your background splash?

Comment: And which drawable is that under? Because different folders have dimension limitations and going past that can cause some problems. This was the case for me.