# setting windowBackground in AppTheme results in background disappearing after 3-5 seconds and changing to black screen

Tags: android, android-styles, android-background, app-themes

I have a `AppTheme` that I specify here:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/wallpaper2</item>
</style>
```

as well as I set it in my manifest to my various `Activities`.

However when the app launches it shows the background for, maybe a second? - and then promptly resets it to black...

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nanospark.cnc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name=".CustomIOIO"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileCreateActivity"
            android:label="@string/profilecreationpageheader" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactCreateActivity"
            android:label="@string/contactcreationpageheader">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EventCreateActivity"
            android:label="@string/eventcreationpageheader">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I could only find one question similar and this was it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160920/android-window-background-image-disappears-5-10-seconds-after-the-app-is-started#comment41164618_26160920

Comment: Can you post manifest? What's in wallpaper2? Is it only black background (widgets stay) or everything goes away?

Comment: Widgets stay; wallpaper2 is just a background jpg I took off of google images to test; and I will add manifest shortly.

Comment: Try setting the theme only to application. The activities inherit it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate caches...
2. Remove app from emulator/device and install app again.

It helped me.